# The database has reached its size quota. Partition or delete data, drop indexes, or consult the documentation for possible resolutions

Tags: azure-sql-database

We are using Azure SQL Database with 32 GB Storage. I have checked the storage utilization from Azure portal and it is showing me 68% used (22 GB). However, when I am trying to create an Index, I am getting the bellow error.

> The database has reached its size quota. Partition or delete data,
> drop indexes, or consult the documentation for possible resolutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the database does not have a maximum size set with the following query. This size limit is independent of the size limit of the tier.

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('db1', 'MaxSizeInBytes') AS DatabaseDataMaxSizeInBytes
```

You can change that max size to the limit of the current tier the database is using.

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] MODIFY (MAXSIZE=100MB)
```

Verify also the Azure SQL is not reaching the maximum size for the TempDB. Please visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15#tempdb-database-in-sql-database) documentation to see the current limit for the service tier the database is using.

Comment: ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] MODIFY (MAXSIZE=100MB); --use of parentheses is currently required